# How do I create a C# program that asks for a value between 1 and 100 that uses a loop

Tags: c#

so I am trying to create a C# program that asks for a value between 1 and 100 that uses a loop to determine the sum of all values between 1 and the entered value and if the number entered in is less than one or more than 100 it prints out "Sorry. Try again." I've been working on this for days but I can't get it to print the sum, I keep getting 0 and whenever I test it and enter a number under one or over 100, it won't print the error message I want. Here is the code:

```
using System;

namespace PrintSumL
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        Console.WriteLine("Enter a beginning value between 1 and 100");
        int s = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());


        int sum = 0;

        Console.WriteLine("Sum of values: " + sum);
        Console.ReadKey();


        Random rand = new Random();
        rand.Next(1, 51);


        while (0 < s && s < 101)
        {
            sum += s;
            s++;
            if (s < 0 && 101 < s)
            {

                Console.WriteLine("Invalid input. Try again.");
            }

            {

            }
            {

            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: `while (0 < s && s < 101)` mean that inner code block will not be executed if `s` is outside of range 0 and 101. So "sorry" message will never be shown.

Comment: There is a formula for sum of numbers 1 to N: `1+2+...+N = N(N+1)/2`.  If they enter 50, you could just calculate `sum = 50 * 51 / 2`.

Comment: `if (s < 0 && 101 < s)`, that can never be `true`. A value cannot be lower than `0`, so it must be negative, and bigger than `101`, which is clearly a positive number. You want to use `||`, not `&&`.

Comment: It'll still say that the sum is 0 if I type a number like 20

Comment: Of course, you never print the value of sum _after_ has been calculated

Comment: how do I rearrange all of this? this is confusing

Comment: Just move the writing of sum after the loop, then you will notice the error in your calculation logic

Comment: sum cannot be used before its declared

Answer (score 2):

You can think of the program as executing line by line from top to bottom, and only moving back up when it reaches the end of the while loop. The end of the while loop is the `}` that matches the `{` at the start of the loop.

Knowing that, you can see why it always says sum is zero. From your code:

```
int sum = 0;

Console.WriteLine("Sum of values: " + sum);
```

Since the program executes "line by line from top to bottom", it will first set `sum` to 0, and then print sum out. So it will always print `"Sum of values: 0"`. If you want it to print out the sum *after* it has calculated it, then you need to move the `WriteLine` down below where the sum is calculated.

The same issue applies to the `"Invalid input. Try again."`: the line that prints this statement appears after `while (0 < s && s < 101)`, so will only execute if `s` is between 0 and 101. Since you're trying to catch the scenario where `s` is **not** between 0 and 101, you'll need to move the statement to above the `while` loop.

So, to fix your immediate problems, just do two things:

1) move the two lines

```
Console.WriteLine("Sum of values: " + sum);
Console.ReadKey();
```

to after the while loop (just after the `}` which is at the same level of indentation as `while`).

2) move the three lines

```
if (s < 0 && 101 < s)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Invalid input. Try again.");
}
```

up to just below `int s = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());`, and then double check the logic. It sounds like you want to print the statement if `s` is less than zero **or** `s` is greater than 101.

Comment: Still ignoring the elephant in the room. The calc is wrong and that if will never be true

Comment: Yes, deliberately so. Important to take baby steps now for edification, instead of just solving it. Lots of learning will come once the procedural nature of `C#` becomes apparent. Hint to the OP: consider `s--` instead of `s++` and consider why that might make more sense.

Comment: it is not giving me the error message if I type in a number like 105 or -1

Comment: and it's only supposed to print out the sum once such as "sum of values is 330"'

Comment: Great, so you've found your next two problems. For what values of s is `s < 0 && 101 < s`? 105? -1? 50? Actually none of them. Try `s<0 || 101<s`. And if the sum is being printed out multiple times, then you put the `WriteLine` in the while loop instead of after it. At this point, the Q&A style of this site is not useful to you. If you need helping working through multiple problems, consider a forum or tutorial group.

Answer (score 1):

if loops are a requirement you should follow Heath Raftery instruction

else you could write something like:

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
 {
     Console.WriteLine("Enter a beginning value between 1 and 100");
     int s = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
     if (s < 0 || s > 100)
         Console.WriteLine("Invalid input. Try again.");
     else
         Console.WriteLine($"Sum of values: {Enumerable.Range(1,s).Sum()}");
 }
```

or as haldo commented you could just use the formula of  `N * (N+1) / 2` and replace the last WriteLine with:

```
Console.WriteLine($"Sum of values: {s * (s+1) / 2}")
```

Comment: Of course this will work but you are ignoring the constraint. _using a loop_ clearly this is some kind of first class homework and using Enumerables and Linq is hardly an argument for a newbie coder

Comment: It has to be a loop

Comment: If we're not using loops you could also just use formula `N * (N+1) / 2` and not enumerate anything.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            while (true)
            {
                Console.Write("Enter a number between 1 and 100: ");
                int Number = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                if (Number < 0 || Number > 100)
                    Console.WriteLine("Sorry. Try again.");
                else
                {
                    int sum = 0;
                    for (int i = 1; i <= Number; i++)
                    {
                        sum = sum + i;
                    }

                    Console.WriteLine("Sum of values: " + sum);
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an algorithm that works...

```
        Console.WriteLine("Enter a value between 1 and 100");
        var input = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        int sum = 0;
        if (input<1 || input>100) {
            Console.WriteLine("Sorry, Try again");
        }
        else{
            while(input > 2){
                input-=1;
                sum+=input;
             }
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Sum of values: " + sum);
```